# Multiple GroupBy and Concatenation with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas

I'm confronted to a specific use case and I'm unable to find a way to solve it with pandas.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   biz_id  offer_id  update_timestamp   amount
0    1        1         2013-04-30        5
1    2        1         2014-05-30        7
2    1        2         2015-11-30        3
3    0        2         2013-08-30        5
4    1        2         2015-06-12        9
```

The SQL operation that I want to make can be described like this:

I want for every `biz_id` to get the `offer_id` row that has the latest `timestamp`. Something like this:

#### Step 1: group by `biz_id`

```
   biz_id  offer_id  update_timestamp   amount
0    1        1         2013-04-30        5
2             2         2015-11-30        3
4             2         2015-06-12        9
1    2        1         2014-05-30        7
3    0        2         2013-08-30        5
```

#### Step 2: filter out by the latest timestamp

```
   biz_id  offer_id  update_timestamp   amount
0    1        1         2013-04-30        5
2             2         2015-11-30        3
1    2        1         2014-05-30        7
3    0        2         2013-08-30        5
```

Unfortunately, i'm unable to find a way to achieve this.

I tried something like this:

```
df.groupby('offer_id').agg({'update_timestamp': np.max}).reset_index()
```

But it's not achieving what I want because I'm not doing the grouping by `biz_id` and when I try to accumulate the group_by operations and the aggregations, it doesn't work and I don't manage to get the `amount` column.

If somebody has any idea on how to achieve this, I would be very grateful.

Many thanks!

Comment: Write the query, what you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get index of `max` datetimes by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) by both columns `biz_id` and `offer_id` and then select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['update_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['update_timestamp'])
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['biz_id','offer_id'])['update_timestamp'].idxmax()]
print (df)
   biz_id  offer_id update_timestamp  amount
3       0         2       2013-08-30       5
0       1         1       2013-04-30       5
2       1         2       2015-11-30       3
1       2         1       2014-05-30       7
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby(['biz_id','offer_id'])['update_timestamp'].idxmax())
biz_id  offer_id
0       2           3
1       1           0
        2           2
2       1           1
Name: update_timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Alternative solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values('update_timestamp')
        .groupby(['biz_id','offer_id'], as_index=False)
        .last())
print (df)

   biz_id  offer_id update_timestamp  amount
0       0         2       2013-08-30       5
1       1         1       2013-04-30       5
2       1         2       2015-11-30       3
3       2         1       2014-05-30       7
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values('update_timestamp').drop_duplicates(['biz_id','offer_id'], 'last')
print (df)

   biz_id  offer_id update_timestamp  amount
0       1         1       2013-04-30       5
3       0         2       2013-08-30       5
1       2         1       2014-05-30       7
2       1         2       2015-11-30       3
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, I'm trying this approach right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(['biz_id', 'offer_id', 'timestamp']).groupby(['biz_id','offer_id']).head(1)
```

Output:

```
biz_id  offer_id  timestamp      amount
0         2       2013-08-30       5
1         1       2013-04-30       5
1         2       2015-11-30       3
2         1       2014-05-30       7
```